# How to translate this text

Tags: перевод

Can you, please, help me translate this into english?

> – Я знаю, – сказала Фрида, – что вы пишете новеллы. Могу я их прочесть? Они у вас при себе?
>   – При себе, – говорю, – у меня лишь те, которых ещё нет.

Comment: Is it from Dovlatov?

Comment: Here the wordplay like "with me" vs "within me". I think that should be enough.

Comment: What part of this you cannot understand? "asking for translations" and "seeking phrases in English" are considered off-topics on this site.

Comment: As I know, you write novels - Frida said. - Could I read them? Do you have them with you?                                                                                               - Yep, - I'm saying - I have only those which don't exist yet.                         He means that he has only unwritten novels in his mind and nothing else with him.

Comment: It's a nice question with game of words.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. I'm new on this site and I didn't know that I'm not allowed to ask for translations. I wasn't sure of what  у меня лишь те, которых еще нет meant; I provided the whole sentence because I know that the context is sometimes more important than the word itself. Beside that, I'm in a hurry to write my Bachelor paper. Hope I didn't upset you!

Comment: Yes, it is from Serghey Dovlatov's "Хочу быть сильным" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frida said: I know that you write short stories. Can I read them? Do you have them with you?
I answered: Only those are with me that haven't existed yet.

The narrator means that he doesn't carry hard copies of his stories, instead he has some ideas for future stories to be written.